# react native "attempt to set value to an immutable object"

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I'm creating a draggable box. which I can drag anywhere on the screen but I'm getting this error which says that "**You attempted to set the key `_value` on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen**". Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong.

My Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Button,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions,
  PanResponder,
  Animated,
  View
} from 'react-native'

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'




export default class Home extends Component{

componentWillMount(){

  this.animatedValue = new Animated.ValueXY();

this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({

 onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
  onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
  onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {



      },

  onPanResponderMove:Animated.event([


null,{dx: this.animatedValue.x , dy:this.animatedValue.y}

    ]),  
  onPanResponderRelease: (e, gestureState) => { 
      },       
})
}

  render(){

    const animatedStyle = {

      transform:this.animatedValue.getTranslateTransform()
    }

    return(

        <View style={styles.container}>

        <Animated.View style={[styles.box ,animatedStyle]} {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}>


        <Text>Home</Text>


        </Animated.View>
        </View>
      )
  }
}


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  box:{

height:90,
width:90,
textAlign:'center'



  }
});
```

Comment: Got a line number? My guess is it has to do with that `const animatedStyle`, since "immutable" means "cannot be changed". `this.animatedValue.getTranslateTransform()` may not be constant. I'm not 100% sure, but changing `const` to `var` might do the trick, but I'm not sure why you set that to const to begin with so maybe I'm wrong. LMK if it works, and if so I'll add this as an Answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Thank you for looking forward to my question sir, I tried but still same error. :(

Comment: not sure if this is the issue, but you misspelled 'transform' in animatedStyle

Comment: thanx for pointing out @Matt Aft. I Typed it wrong on stack although it is right in my code.

Comment: @MattAft wow I actually had transform spelled wrong in my code.  thanks! haha

Answer (score 7):

In my case I got this error because I forgot to change the `View` into `Animated.View`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. This will solve your issue.
You need to initialize animatedValue in state object to make it work.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    animatedValue: new Animated.ValueXY()
  }
}

onPanResponderMove:Animated.event([
 null,{dx: this.state.animatedValue.x , dy:this.state.animatedValue.y}
]),
```

Comment: I have the animatedValue in state, but I get the same error.